# uWSGI - Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi

I'm trying to use uWSGI with processes and threads together, but when I enabled threads I got this errors (daemonize log):

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
[deadlock-detector] a process holding a robust mutex died. recovering...
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 6617) died, killed by signal 6 :( trying respawn ...
```

I'm using Python 3.4.2 and uWSGI 2.0.14 on Debian Jessie.

uWSGI config file:

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/test

chdir = %(base)
module = test.wsgi:application
home = /home/user/.pyenv/test-3.4.2

master = true
processes = 4
threads = 5 ;I enabled this line
pidfile = %(base)/test.pid
harakiri = 30
post-buffering = 8000
min-worker-lifetime = 60
die-on-term = true
stats = %(base)/stats.sock
thunder-lock = true

socket = %(base)/test.sock
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true

max-requests = 5000
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/test.log
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/daemonize.log
```